Not able to run puppeteer with Svelte, internal error 500 when I import puppeteer
I have made a new project using the following command:
npx degit sveltejs/template svelte-app

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0v5WcrU_vM&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9hlbrVO_2QFVqVPhlZmz7tO&index=19&t=30s
Then I installed puppeteer at the root of my project:
npm install puppeteer

Then when I import puppeteer in the App.svelte:
<script>import puppeteer from "puppeteer";</script>

And start the server:
npm run dev

Here is the error:
> svelte-app@1.0.0 dev
> rollup -c -w

rollup v3.29.4
bundles src/main.js → public/build/bundle.js...
(!) "this" has been rewritten to "undefined"
https://rollupjs.org/troubleshooting/#error-this-is-undefined
node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/ScreenRecorder.js
4:  * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
5:  */
6: var __runInitializers = (this && this.__runInitializers) || function (thisArg, initializers, value) {
                            ^
7:     var useValue = arguments.length > 2;
8:     for (var i = 0; i < initializers.length; i++) {
...and 5 other occurrences
node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/QueryHandler.js
4:  * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
5:  */
6: var __addDisposableResource = (this && this.__addDisposableResource) || function (env, value, async) {
                                  ^
7:     if (value !== null && value !== void 0) {
8:         if (typeof value !== "object" && typeof value !== "function") throw new TypeError("Object expected.");
...and 3 other occurrences
node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/HandleIterator.js
4:  * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
5:  */
6: var __addDisposableResource = (this && this.__addDisposableResource) || function (env, value, async) {
                                  ^
7:     if (value !== null && value !== void 0) {
8:         if (typeof value !== "object" && typeof value !== "function") throw new TypeError("Object expected.");
...and 3 other occurrences

...and 28 other files
(!) Plugin node-resolve: preferring built-in module 'buffer' over local alternative at 'C:\Users\ORDINATEUR\Desktop\Projects\Website\SerieFollower\node_modules\buffer\index.js', pass 'preferBuiltins: false' to disable this behavior or 'preferBuiltins: true' to disable this warning
[!] (plugin commonjs--resolver) RollupError: Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)
node_modules/escodegen/package.json (2:10)
1: {
2:     "name": "escodegen",
             ^
3:     "description": "ECMAScript code generator",
4:     "homepage": "http://github.com/estools/escodegen",
    at error (C:\Users\ORDINATEUR\Desktop\Projects\Website\SerieFollower\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:353:30)
    at Module.error (C:\Users\ORDINATEUR\Desktop\Projects\Website\SerieFollower\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15237:16)
    at Module.tryParse (C:\Users\ORDINATEUR\Desktop\Projects\Website\SerieFollower\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15968:25)
    at Module.setSource (C:\Users\ORDINATEUR\Desktop\Projects\Website\SerieFollower\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15569:39)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (C:\Users\ORDINATEUR\Desktop\Projects\Website\SerieFollower\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:25804:20)


Does this answer your question? How to run Puppeteer code in any web browser?

Puppeteer runs a local instance of Chromium, you cannot execute it in the browser (e.g. any Svelte code).

Puppeteer is a Node.js library [...]

If you are using SvelteKit, you can use Puppeteer in *.server.js/ts files, only.
